# OpenGl/GLSL - More Efficient Methods of Drawing Multiple Triangles

Tags: arrays, opengl, matrix, glsl

So in my program, I'm using OpenGL/GLSL to construct a square and texturing it.

It's modern `OpenGL 4.0+` so doesn't use `glBegin`/`glEnd` etc.

My square is made up of 2 triangles, constructed using `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);`

As you can see with my function below, it creates 2 triangles. I'm using 18 vertices in an array when really I only need 12 to create a square because 6 of them are used in both triangles. Its the same with the 24 colours and 8 text coordinates.

```
void Ground::constructGeometry(Shader* myShader)
{
    //Triangle 1 (x,y,z)
    vert[0]  =-dimY;  vert[1] = dimX;  vert[2] = dimZ; //Point 2
    vert[3]  =-dimY;  vert[4] =-dimX;  vert[5] = dimZ; //Point 1
    vert[6]  = dimY;  vert[7] =-dimX;  vert[8] = dimZ; //Point 4
    //Triangle 2 (x,y,z)
    vert[9]  = dimY; vert[10] =-dimX; vert[11] = dimZ; //Point 4
    vert[12] = dimY; vert[13] = dimX; vert[14] = dimZ; //Point 3
    vert[15] =-dimY; vert[16] = dimX; vert[17] = dimZ; //Point 2
    //Colours 1 (r,g,b,a)
    col[0]  = 1.0f;   col[1] = 0.0f;   col[2] = 0.0f;  col[3] = 1.0f;
    col[4]  = 1.0f;   col[5] = 0.0f;   col[6] = 0.0f;  col[7] = 1.0f;
    col[8]  = 1.0f;   col[9] = 0.0f;  col[10] = 0.0f; col[11] = 1.0f;
    //Colours 2 (r,g,b,a)
    col[12] = 1.0f;  col[13] = 0.0f;  col[14] = 0.0f; col[15] = 1.0f;
    col[16] = 1.0f;  col[17] = 0.0f;  col[18] = 0.0f; col[19] = 1.0f;
    col[20] = 1.0f;  col[21] = 0.0f;  col[22] = 0.0f; col[23] = 1.0f;

    //(s,t) coords for Tri 1
    tex[0] = 0.0;   tex[1] = 1.0;
    tex[2] = 0.0;   tex[3] = 0.0;
    tex[4] = 1.0;   tex[5] = 0.0;
    //(s,t) coords for Tri 2
    tex[6]  = 1.0;  tex[7] = 0.0;
    tex[8]  = 1.0;  tex[9] = 1.0;
    tex[10] = 0.0; tex[11] = 1.0;

    glGenVertexArrays(2, &m_vaoID[0]);
    glBindVertexArray(m_vaoID[0]);

    glGenBuffers(3, m_vboID);

    GLint vertexLocation= glGetAttribLocation(myShader->handle(), "in_Position");
    GLint colorLocation= glGetAttribLocation(myShader->handle(), "in_Color");
    GLint texCoordLocation = glGetAttribLocation(myShader->handle(), "in_TexCoord");
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(myShader->handle(), "DiffuseMap"), 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboID[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, totalVerts *sizeof(GLfloat), vert, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0); 

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboID[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, totalCols *sizeof(GLfloat), col, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colorLocation, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vboID[2]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, totalTexs *sizeof(GLfloat), tex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

How can this be made more efficient so when making the second triangle I can use vert[x] that's already been used instead of declaring the same ones again (points 4 and 2)?
And the same with colours?

And how does this affect my rendering function below?

```
void Ground::render(GLuint texName, Shader* myShader)                                   
{
    glUseProgram(myShader->handle());       //find shader passed
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);  //blending needed to use alpha channel
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glBindVertexArray(m_vaoID[0]);          //select first VAO
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);       //draw first object 0-3, then second 3-6

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glUseProgram(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);                   //unbind the vertex array object
}
```

Obviously I guess it's OK to do it the way I have for only 2 triangles, but I wouldn't want to write out hundreds of vertices if, for some reason, I suddenly wanted a whole bunch of triangles...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `glDrawElements()` instead of `glDrawArrays()` if you would like to reuse vertices.

`glDrawElements` takes an index array argument, which allows you to specify the indices of vertices in the vertex array, making it possible to use them multiple times.

Comment: Ohhh... So simple! I'll look into it. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the (correct) answers using `glDrawElements`, you could use `glDrawArrays` with `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` instead of `GL_TRIANGLES`. A fan uses the first three vertices to draw a triangle, then each subsequent vertex will generate a triangle using the new vertex, the last vertex and the first vertex. Now you only need four vertices (arranged counter-clockwise) in your array, and the call looks like:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
```

Comment: Oh cool. That's handy to know. Thanks for posting. I'll also give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

What you asking for is called *indexed rendering*. The basic idea is to provide an [index buffer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) those elements reference the vertex IDs in your vertex arrays. So for two triangles sharing one edge, you can define just the 4 corner vertices and can use and index array like `{0,1,2, 2,1,3}`. You will have to use [`glDrawElements()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml) to do the drawing.

You might also want to have a look at [this wiki page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Direct_rendering) to get an overview of what drawing paths are available in modern GL.